# How to show ggplot from external function in shiny R application?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I need to create shiny app which will create a plot basing on dropdown menu choise. The whole computation part is pretty complicated and so is the plot – I created a function which is returning ggplot and I just wanted to show it in the app.
My idea looks as follows:

```
library(shiny)
source('Analysis/function_external.R')
list_names = c('a', 'b', 'c')
ui <- fluidPage(
    selectInput("data", "Select data to plot", choices = list_names)
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

  observe({function_external(input$data)})

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

It is making function run every time I change the input, but it does not show anything. I would really appreciate if you can point me into good direction.

Comment: it's hard to help without knowing what does function_external do, can you share a reproducible example?

Comment: It takes some external data, process basing on a, b or c when returns ggplot such as return_plot = ggplot(data=x, etc), when return(return_plot). Originally it was just ploting without returning, but I thought that maybe I will try that way to pass the plot to shiny. I will try to create reproducible example later, because it will take me a while.

Comment: `output$my_complicated_plot <- renderPlot({ function_external(input$data) })` should work, provided you add `my_complicated_plot` to your ui function.

Comment: Maybe I do not understand something clearly but this solution does not run the function at all in my case. When I run it with observe I see                             > runApp()

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6750
old-style crs object detected; please recreate object with a recent sf::st_crs()
old-style crs object detected; please recreate object with a recent sf::st_crs()
Cyclones names :Number of locatiosn to analyse : 30 – which is normal for this function. in case you provided only runApp()

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6750 and nothing is happening.

Comment: Okay, it seems that i forgot to add it to ui. It works now, thank you a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

output$my_complicated_plot <- renderPlot({ function_external(input$data) })
Solved the issue.